# Nesting stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need create a stored proc that will return a list of a code, and then I need to call another stored proc to review each code, one by one.

How can I do this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[paBltBuscarBoletasASA] @id_Asa int  
AS
DECLARE @Query int, @Contador int 
SET @Contador = 0
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;  
      SET @Query = (
                SELECT 
                    localizacion.c_Fk_IdBoleta
                FROM 
                    Blt_Boleta as boleta, Fnc_Localizacion as localizacion
                WHERE 
                    boleta.c_Pk_IdBoleta = localizacion.c_Fk_IdBoleta AND
                    localizacion.si_CodAsa = @id_Asa) //This query give the list of Codes. For example 45550711, 40480711, 80110711... etc

    exec dbo.paBltMarcarErroresBoleta @Query //And here I need send one by one that list of Codes
END
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Declare a CURSOR for the query that you are setting equal to @Query, and then insert into the variable each subsequent value in a WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 loop.  Then pass the @Query variable to the second stored procedure as you are currently doing.  Here is an example:

```
DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT localizacion.c_Fk_IdBoleta
FROM Blt_Boleta as boleta, Fnc_Localizacion as localizacion
WHERE boleta.c_Pk_IdBoleta = localizacion.c_Fk_IdBoleta AND 
localizacion.si_CodAsa = @id_Asa

OPEN myCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @Query

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    exec dbo.paBltMarcarErroresBoleta @Query
    //do additional processing

FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @Query
END

CLOSE myCursor
DEALLOCATE myCursor
```

Additional cursor help:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

Comment: Ok, Now How Can I save the results of second SP in a temporal table?

Comment: Just do `INSERT INTO #tempTable EXEC dbo.paBltMarcarErroresBoleta @Query`.  More information and options can be found here http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html

Comment: Other question, the second SP returns a Table with 5 columns(Description_Error, Id_Boleta, Name_Boleta, Cod_Asa, Cultivo), I need declare this columns in the temporal table?, The idea is shows this table in a CrystalReport, but I need to know if this is necesary?

Comment: When you declare the table you must indicate what columns it will have. `CREATE TABLE #tempTable ( description_error varchar, id_boleta int, name_boleta varchar, cod_asa varchar, cultivo varchar)` and then change the insert to be something like `INSERT INTO #tempTable (description_error, id_boleta, name_boleta, cod_asa, cultivo) EXEC dbo.paBltMarcarErroresBoleta @Query`.  This way it knows where to stick each column returned.  I wasnt sure what type the columns should be so I just guessed.  Change those as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider adding an scalar function and call it in your query, like:

```
SELECT 
    localizacion.c_Fk_IdBoleta,
    dbo.checkCode(localizacion.c_Fk_IdBoleta) as Check
FROM 
    Blt_Boleta as boleta, Fnc_Localizacion as localizacion
WHERE 
    boleta.c_Pk_IdBoleta = localizacion.c_Fk_IdBoleta AND
    localizacion.si_CodAsa = @id_Asa
```